# (Python) Why is it returning 9.0 instead of 9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, integer

Trying to make a simple counter in python for a project in a "Learn Python Book"

Brief: Write a program that counts for the user. Let the user enter the starting number, the ending number and the amount by which to count.

Problem: Ok so basically trying to make sure that if the user were to          type
         in (start at 2 and count to 17 in 2's) that the program would flag         it up as not possible.

```
print ("Welcome to the program for those who are to lazy to count")
print ("You must be really really lazy too use this")

input ("\n Press any key to continue")

Num1 = int(input ("Please Enter Starting Number: \n"))
Num2 = int(input ("Please Enter Ending Number: \n"))
count = int(input ("Count up in: \n"))

differ = (Num2 - Num1)

test =(differ/count)

if isinstance(test,int):
 while (Num1 < Num2):
  Num1 += count
  print (Num1)   
  isinstance( test, int )
else:
    print ("Sorry Starting at",Num1,"You can not get to",Num2,"counting up by",count,)
```

(( I did some testing and found that the variable test was always coming        back as a float.A whole number for example 9 would be 9.0 which would of course make my if statement false. Can anyone explain why this is occurring and how to fix/get around it?))

Comment: That's what happens when you use division: it returns a `float`.

Comment: Is there no way round this problem? because if i just convert it into an int then there would be no point in the IF statement

Comment: Python 3 uses // for integer division.

Comment: Forcing integer division would defeat the purpose of the test. See @wilbur's answer.

Comment: I see but then i imagine i would have the problem of everything being an Integer!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should test to see if `(differ % count) == 0` instead of checking to see if your `test` is an integer. The result of your division operation is always a float because python 3 defaults to floating point division. It can be forced to perform integer division with `//`.

See the [python docs for modulo](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much *didn't even think about using modulo" :) very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

wilbur's answer is the best, but if you still want to use division instead of modulo, instead of checking `if isinstance(test, int)` which checks if test is really an integer type (which is not true for 9.0), you can try `if test.is_integer()` which will return `True` if it's a float with an integer value (which is true for 9.0).

This is not an approach you can count on because division with floats is imprecise. Using a modulo operator is a lot more reliable!

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 does floating-point division by default.  If you want to force integer division, express double slashes in your quotient (`differ // count`).

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 `/` always returns float. For integer division, use `//`.